# CSS hover, don't return to original size

Tags: css

When I hover over image it changes size but when I move my cursor away it returns to original size. Is it possible to prevent returning to original size (without JS)?
Example: height:200px
on hover height:400px, and when I move cursor away height stays 400px.

```
#camera{
        height:280px;
        width:400px;
        transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
        overflow:hidden;
}
#camera:hover{
              height:450px;
              width:700px;
              transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: You need to post your css or we cannot do anthing.

Comment: @Imagine Studios yeah it works, but it return so original size(280x400) and I don't want that.

Comment: is not possible with css only

Comment: You can't make it with pure CSS

Comment: `$(function(){
$('#camera').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({width: "700px",height:'400px'});
});
});`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#camera', function(){
    $(this).css("width", "450px");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1f3n2ss/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way if you play with a checkbox that its actually not visible to the eye. This will use the click event and not the hover state.

This solution does not use Javascript or JQuery or anything else, just HTML and CSS.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gw1ttwqm/).

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myoption_01_item" name="myoption" />
<label for="myoption_01_item">
    <img src="http://www.funchap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/help-dog-picture.jpg" border="0" />
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"][name="myoption"][id^="myoption_"][id$="_item"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"][name="myoption"][id^="myoption_"][id$="_item"]:not(:checked) + label img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;

    -webkit-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
}
input[type="checkbox"][name="myoption"][id^="myoption_"][id$="_item"]:checked + label img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 230px;

    -webkit-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .200s ease-in-out, height .200s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You CANT achieve that only by using CSS! CSS checks for states and you have said. 
When my image is on default state do this,
When my image is on state "HOVER" do this {...}.

So basically your image switches between those two states you have declared. You can achieve what you want with jQuery like this:

```
<img class="myImage" src="....">

<script>
$('.myImage).hover(function(){
    $(this).css(width, "300px");
});
</script>
```